# Determine WiFi channel from beacon frame

Tags: python-2.7, network-programming, wifi

I am currently working on a wifi sniffer based on Scapy. 
It is currently nothing fancy, it simply looks for packets with the dot11 layer and picks only the packets with the correct subtypes. 
Now my question is how do I determine the correct channel of the AP?

I'm aware you can extract the channel from the captured packets, but the channel field seems to just contain whichever channel the wifi card was on when the packet was captured. However, due to channel overlap you will see beacons from the same AP on up to four different channels.

So, is there any way to get the real channel out of Scapy?

Comment: That sort of data usually is in the RadioTap header rather than Dot11 :/

Comment: Yes, you get the channel with `pkt[RadioTap].Channel`. But that is just whatever channel the wifi card happens to be set to at the moment.